# BlackBerry emulator doesnt load app

Tags: blackberry, cordova, ripple

I have Ripple which im using to test app made for android. App is written in html5 and javascript, so i used the same files as i used in android version.
I have changed only phonegap file (blackberry ver), and i add:

- config.xml
- plugins.xml
- ext/phonegap.1.2.0.jar
- resources/icon.png
- resources/icon_hover.png
- resources/loading_foreground.png

In Ripple it works fine, but when i created cod file, i can't load it into BlackBerry emulator or BlackBerry device.

Im using BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5 to create cod file.

Comment: What does it mean "can't load it into BlackBerry emulator"? What have you tried to load the app to simulator (BlackBerry does not have emulators, only simulators). What errors did you get? Give us more details about the issue.

Comment: If its simulator, I can't load it in simulator. I don't see any errors while I'm loading cod file. I click load app or theme and choose cod file, next I see spinning circle, and when its finish apps icon doesn't appears in simulator. I did the same process with different app and it was fine. There are no logs where I could check what's going on or i couldnt find it.

Comment: When you have uploaded your cod file to simulator, have you checked "Downloads" folder? If so, and there was no app visible, generate alx file in WebWorks for your cod file and isntall this cod file via BlackBerry Desktop Manager to the simulator. In simulator menu select "Simulate -> USB Cable connected". Then run javaloader.exe (it can be found in JDE/bin folder) and list all installed cod files  into the simulator. Is your cod file present in the list?

Comment: As you can see below i found solution. Also i couldn't check it in your way, "USB Cable Connected" was disabled in my simulator. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution:

BlackBerry Knowledge Base article: [The maximum size of a BlackBerry smartphone application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/1300209)
Support forum thread: ["Load java program" on simulator and "Jvm: errors in .cod" problem](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/quot-Load-java-program-quot-on-simulator-and-quot-Jvm-errors-in/td-p/352624)

The cod file was too big, and files inside ware too big.  The cod file should be less than 8128 KB

I reduced the image file sizes. A few files were very big, for example one file was 1.21 MB, now it is 287 KB. Quality isn't so good, but it works.